# Two conditions for query in MySQL with EXISTS

Tags: mysql, exists

I am trying to get the authors which satisfies the two conditions with EXISTS conditions. However, I keep getting all of the entries in the author table when the subqueries actually work.
Could anyone tell me what is actually wrong with my query? I am currently counting the number of entries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM author
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT A.author_id, A.author_name
FROM author AS A 
INNER JOIN author_publication AS AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%'
GROUP BY A.author_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=10)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT A.author_id, A.author_name
FROM author AS A 
INNER JOIN author_publication AS AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
GROUP BY A.author_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=10)
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subqueries are lacking any relation to your main query. So for every record you ask the same question: "Does an author with at least ten publications of a certain type exist in the table?". The answer is the same for every record, so you get all records back. What you really want to ask is: "Do at least ten publications of a certain type exist *for this author* in the table?"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM author
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM author_publication AS AP 
  INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
  WHERE AP.author_id = author.author_id
  AND P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%'
  GROUP BY AP.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
) 
AND EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM author_publication AS AP 
  INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
  WHERE AP.author_id = author.author_id
  AND P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
  GROUP BY AP.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
);
```

If you want to write non-correlated subqueries, use `IN` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM author
WHERE author_id IN 
(
  SELECT AP.author_id
  FROM author_publication AS AP 
  INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
  WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%'
  GROUP BY AP.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
) 
AND author_id IN 
(
  SELECT AP.author_id
  FROM author_publication AS AP 
  INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
  WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
  GROUP BY A.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
);
```

And here is how to do this with a single subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
  SELECT AP.author_id
  FROM author_publication AS AP 
  INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
  WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%' OR P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
  GROUP BY AP.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%' THEN 1 END) >= 10
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%' THEN 1 END) >= 10
) found_authors;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! That really cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.author_id)
FROM
  author AS A
    INNER JOIN author_publication AS AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
    INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
WHERE
  P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%' OR P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
GROUP BY A.author_id
HAVING COUNT(A.author_id) >= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to correlate to subqueries to the main query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM author as AA
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT A.author_id, A.author_name
FROM author AS A 
INNER JOIN author_publication AS AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/pvldb/%'
AND AA.author_id=A.author_id
GROUP BY A.author_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=10)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT A.author_id, A.author_name
FROM author AS A 
INNER JOIN author_publication AS AP ON A.author_id = AP.author_id
INNER JOIN publication AS P ON AP.pub_id = P.pub_id
WHERE P.pub_key LIKE '%/sigmod/%'
AND AA.author_id=A.author_id
GROUP BY A.author_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=10)
;
```